# numbered table of content in md_document or github_document

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr

I am having trouble with the table of content in a md_document or github_document.

If I do that, the TOC is displayed in the rendered document, but the links do not work:

```
---
output:
  md_document: 
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 4
---

### 1. Header

### 2. Header

#### 2.1. Subheader

#### 2.2 Subheader
```

Same problem with github_document; but no problem with html_document.

If I remove the numbers in the section headers, the links in the TOC work.

Is there a way to have section numbers in an md or github_document?

Unfortunately, GitHub does not display HTML docs nicely, so I have to use either md or github_document, but my file is long and the numbering would help to follow its structure.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

What if you back "md_document:" up so it is directly under the "Output:"? You said your links work when you remove the numbers in the section headers, but I don't see any links?

Comment: I meant the links in the TOC: when you click on a section header in the TOC, the view should move to this section in the document. With numbered sections, it apparently doesn't work.

Comment: I agree it is not obvious that the links of the TOC do not work because my example is too short. Just try adding lines between the headers.